# Search and replace specific code in xml using perl

Tags: xml, perl, search, replace

I am new to Perl, I have a task to replace or remove comment part (`<!--`) in multiple XML files, after replace I need to move those multiple XML files to other directories. I am illustrating below my `D:\folder1\` having many xml files `a.xml`, `b.xml`, `c.xml` so on, after replace I need to move all the files from `folder1` to `D:\folder2\`.

I tried one file by replacing `-` and `@@@` but I don't have idea to remove comment line (`<!--add aaa -->`) from xml files in directory.

My Perl code follow below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $tag = 'SHORT_DESC';

open my $input_file, '<', 'test.xml' or die $!;
open my $output_file, '>', 'test_out.xml' or die $!;

my $input;
{
  local $/;               #Set record separator to undefined.
  $input = <$input_file>; #This allows the whole input file to be read at once.
}

$input =~ s/&/@@@/g;
$input =~ s/^- (?=<)//gm;
$input =~ s/<header[^>]*>\K\s*<header[^>]*>//gis;
close $input_file or die $!;
print {$output_file} $input;
close $output_file or die $!;
```

And my XML is

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<!-- Order details-->
<order>
<Names>
<!-- Names-->
<content>This is dummy content</content>
</Names>
</order>
```

Comment: Are you typing XML comments incorrectly for a specific reason? Why the reference to `@@@`? Also, `my $input = do { local $/; <$input_file> };` . Also, you are not reading using UTF-8 layer.

Comment: Files coming like this I am not typing

Comment: Are you claiming comments in the files literally use **`<\!--`**? In that case, they are not XML.

Comment: Sinan my requirement is to remove that comment line from the file, its purely xml file, example purpose I changed the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a proper XML handling module. I like [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::XSH2;   # To handle XML.
use Path::Tiny;  # To move files around.

my ($source, $target) = @ARGV;

for my $file (path($source)->children(qr/\.xml$/)) {
    xsh "open $file ; delete //comment() ; save";
    path($file)->copy($target);
    path($file)->remove;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you guide me where I to include the source and destination folder path,  how to include xsh2 module to the program, it is possible other method can implement my task.

Comment: @NachiappanR: The source and target directories should be specified as parameters to the script.

Comment: Thanks choroba, can you say did I need to include xsh2 module, if so please tell me the procedure.

Comment: Even I install the xsh2 using ppm install xsh2 in command prompt but I am facing the error Can't locate XML/XSH2.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::XSH2 module)
(@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at searcn.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at hello.pl line 5.

Comment: I hope the code will work, but only problem is how to include the module XSH2, is any other method to include the same task?

Comment: The module name is `XML::XSH2`, not `xsh2`.